# Cannot read property 'title' of null using vuejs 3

Tags: json, vue.js

i am new to `vuejs3`, i tried using `json` with `vuejs3`, i displayed the courses in view `blog / index`, and when clicking on a course in an `index` it redirect to details of that course clicks, in my case it gives me error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null`.

**blog/index.vue**

```
<template lang="">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6" v-for="post in posts">
          <h1><router-link :to="{ name: 'post-show', params: { id: post.id, slug: post.slug }}">{{ post.title }}</router-link></h1>
          <p class="lead">{{ post.content }}</p>
       </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
      return {
         posts: []
      }
    },
    mounted() {
       fetch('http://localhost:5000/posts')
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => this.posts = data)
          .catch(err => console.log(err))
    },
}
</script>
```

**blog/show.vue**

```
<template lang="">
   <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
   <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
</template>
<script>
export default {

    props: ['id', 'slug'],
    data(){
        return {
            post: null
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        fetch(`http://localhost:5000/posts/${this.id}`)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => this.post = data)
          .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
}
</script>
```

**Router/index.js**

```
  {
        path: '/blog/:id/:slug',
        name: 'post-show',
        component: Show,
        props: true
      },
```

**data/db.json**

```
{
    "posts": [
        {
           "id": 1,
           "title"  : "learn angular",
           "slug"   : "learn-angular",
           "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, possimus."
        },
        {
           "id": 2,
           "title"  : "learn react",
           "slug"   : "learn-react",
           "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, possimus."
        },
        {
           "id": 3,
           "title"  : "learn laravel",
           "slug"   : "learn-laravel",
           "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, possimus."
        },
        {
           "id": 4,
           "title"  : "learn symfony",
           "slug"   : "learn-symfony",
           "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, possimus."
        },
        {
           "id": 5,
           "title"  : "learn jee",
           "slug"   : "learn-jee",
           "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, possimus."
        },
        {
           "id": 6,
           "title"  : "learn php",
           "slug"   : "learn-oracle",
           "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, possimus."
        }
     ],
     "users": []
}
```

Comment: You are getting `Cannot read property 'title' of null` inside `show.vue` component. The data `post` object is initialized as null, and only the `fetch()` function is populating it. Which means that the `fetch()` function doesn't return a value, or it fails for some reason.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is with your `blog/show.vue` file.

Notice how in your data, `post` is set to `null`.

When your component mounts, it attempts to read `post.title` and `post.content` but it fails because `post` does not yet contain those properties.

The method to retrieve and set the post data is only run after the component has been mounted.

One way would be to not display the `<h1>` and `<p>` tags until `post` data is no longer `null` by using an attribute like `v-if="post"`

Alternatively, you can set some default values to your post by making it an object:

```
post: {
   title: '',
   content: '',
}
```

This way, when the component mounts, the properties `title` and `content` exist.

Lastly, you could use a ternary:

```
<h1>{{ post ? post.title: '' }}</h1>
<p>{{ post ? post.content: '' }}</p>
```

In this approach, if post exists it renders the properties - otherwise it renders an empty string.