# Javascript + Vue issue: 'Cannot read property 'value' of null'

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Below I have an input which value I attempt to assign to a variable `v`. My understanding after reading [similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67359217/cannot-read-property-title-of-null-using-vuejs-3) is that, when the page is initialized, the value of the input is `null` and thus cannot be read.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="input"/>
    {{ v }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return { v: document.getElementById("input").value }
  },
}
</script>
```

Two questions immediately pop up:

- Why doesn't `v: null` cause an error? Would it not be equivalent to the code above?
- What is the correct way to assign the value of the input to a variable?

Comment: you should use v-model instead: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `DOM` isn't available in the `data` function. Use `mounted` to access the DOM. If you want two way binding, use `v-model`

From [docs](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#:%7E:text=The%20returned%20object%20should%20ideally%20be%20a%20plain%20object%20that%20only%20represents%20the%20state%20of%20the%20component.)

> It is not recommended to return objects with their own stateful behavior like **browser API objects** and prototype properties. **The returned object should ideally be a plain object that only represents the state of the component.**

```js
<template>
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="input" v-model="v" />
        {{ v }}
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      data(){
        return { v: null }
      },
    }
    </script>
```